# How to upload HDR videos to Facebook?

Tags: video, facebook, uploads, hdr

Facebook already supported HDR video months ago

- https://engineering.fb.com/2023/07/17/video-engineering/hdr-video-reels-meta/
- https://about.fb.com/news/2023/07/facebook-video-keeps-getting-better/

I'm using a Pixel 7 Pro and can view HDR videos on Facebook without problem. However when I upload HDR videos captured with my P7P it always result in an SDR output even though the above articles seem to claim that Android can upload HDR. I've also tried on Z Fold 5 and the same thing happens

So how can I upload HDR videos from my Android phone?